# AngularJs, MVC 4, Nested Models - duplicates being ignored

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I am trying to enhance the following Angular/MVC 4 example:
  https://github.com/danielcsgomes/AngularJS-NetPonto

The code I am using is identical, save
(1) Changing the Process class name to "Product", and,
(2) Adding a "Vendor" class, as an associated class to Product, (and Vendor having a collection of products).

Everything is fine in the API.

However, if I pass the Product class with its associated Vendor, those Products that have the same Vendor will not appear in the list. But, if I make the API return an anonymous type and pass a variable called VendorName, duplicates will appear. Naturally, I would like NOT to use anonymous types so is there a solution to this?

**Exhibit A: Straight forward context.Products.Include("Vendors"):**
[image]

**Exihbit B: As an anonymous type return:**

[image]

**Below are (1) My angular controller to get all products, (2 & 3) The templates to display the data**
[image]

**Template without anonymous type return:**
[image]

**Template with anonymous type return:**
[image]

So my question is this:

**How can I make angular accept duplicate Vendor names for the respective products w/o being required to return the data as an anonymous type?**

Comment: I did, the two GetProducts methods above exemplify the API call

Comment: Oh, i expected a js implementation... Does the data come back from the server? Did you the value of $scope.products (breakpoint)?

Comment: Angular doesn't care about the server response. I don't Angular is ignoring the duplicate values. 
Try to use Chrome (Press F12) or Firefox with Firebug to check your response from server to see what your are getting back.